# X,Y,Z coordinates of an object in the viewer when you select it from the tree

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

is it possible to get the X,Y,Z coordinates of an object when you select it from the object tree itself. I know you can do it when you mouse click on a particular object but i want to get the coordinates when using the navigation tree. Is there a way to get them using the viewer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the model browser's selection behavior is set to default (isolation) then simply subscribe to `Autodesk.Viewing.ISOLATE_EVENT` as you would for selection:

```
NOP_VIEWER.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.ISOLATE_EVENT, e=>{
//NOP_VIEWER.utilities.getBoundingBox().center()
})
```

BTW you can customize interaction behavior for the model browser by specifying the click config here:

```
NOP_VIEWER.modelstructure.clickConfig = {
  click:{ 
    onObject: ["toggleMultipleOverlayedSelection"]
  }
//...
}
```

Comment: Thanks  was able to get it